# ActionBarCompat shows every action in the overflow menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-appcompat

I've started using the ActionBar coming with the AppCompat library. But any action I add to this, shows up in the overflow menu. I'm pretty sure I've skipped something, but I don't know at all. Here's my menu file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/connect_plus"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_google_plus"
        android:title="Connect to Google+"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:titleCondensed="Connect to Google+">
    </item>

</menu>
```

And any configuration in the `onCreate` method from an activity extending from `ActionBarActivity`:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Did I miss something?

Yes.

You need to use your own namespace:

```
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/connect_plus"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_google_plus"
        android:title="Connect to Google+"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always"
        android:titleCondensed="Connect to Google+">
    </item>

</menu>
```

as is shown in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems).

Comment: I am using ActionBarCompat Library, and i am adding menu like this through java code.

@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  menu.add(0, 1, 1, "Search").setIcon(R.drawable.search_icon);
  return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 }

How to add namespace  programmatically when adding menu like this ?

Comment: @BhargavVasani: You do not deal with the namespace. You do, however, need to use `MenuItemCompat` to access things like `setShowAsAction()`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.html#setShowAsAction%28android.view.MenuItem,%20int%29